# Parent taxonomy archive page showing 404 error

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields, custom-post-type

I have created a taxonomy (book) using acf for product post. But its front-end permalink https://heywood.navkiraninfotech.com/books showing 404 page. Althought its child term pages working fine no problem. Am I missing something here or is this a bug of acf? I did flush the permalink settings by saving it but no solution. Template I am using is taxonomy-book.php

[Parent taxonomy archive page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9THAS.jpg)

[Child term archive page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q06nr.jpg)

Comment: Your slug is book and the term is humor. Its like expecting domain.com/product-category/ to be a valid url which is not. Its all good no bugs. If you want books archive then its different story :)

Comment: Yes, I want book archive. How is that possible. @Snuffy

Comment: There are many examples on the web but start here - https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/custom-post-type-template-files/ and this - https://woo.com/document/template-structure/

Comment: I already know this but I want to show all books in book archive page and show respective books in term pages. How its possible? Like example.com/books is it possible? @Snuffy

Comment: by creating archive template for your post type ?

Comment: I have added book taxonomy in product post type. Now there is already archive for product. I just need a archive page for books. @Snuffy

Comment: you have taxonomy product category right ? can you open domain.com/product-category/ ? Follow same logic for any taxonomy :) in your case domain.com/books is taxonomy slug :)

Comment: domain.com/product-category/ not exists, showing 404, as usual. But I want to show all books from book taxonomy

Comment: create page template , create new page and select this template. In the template create query to get all products that have any term in book taxonomy and will show up.